# How to setup/install/enable DC1394 (libdc1394 v2.x) backend for python-opencv (4.1.2) in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: opencv, video-streaming, video-capture, ip-camera

While streaming from IP Camera (Axis M3045-V), I cannot set the buffer size using cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://user:pass@192.168.0.x/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=1920x1080)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 1). However, I can successfully change the buffer size for any webcam. The reason is the following note by OpenCV:

CV_CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE Amount of frames stored in internal buffer memory (note: only supported by DC1394 v 2.x backend currently)

cv2.getBuildInformation() shows that there is no DC1394 in my computer.

I cannot use cv2.CAP_DC1394 in cv2.VideoCapture. However, cv2.CAP_ANY and cv2.CAP_FFMPEG work in my case. Both set the backend to FFMPEG.

backends    =   cv2.videoio_registry.getBackends()# available video backends 
camerabackends  =   cv2.videoio_registry.getCameraBackends()# backends for this camera
getBackeendName =   cap.getBackendName()# Returns used backend API name.

Comment: I installed libdc1394-2.2.6.tar.gz but still cv2.getBuildInformation() shows that    Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (58.62.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.35.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.36.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.6.100)
      avresample:                NO
    GStreamer:                   NO
    v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)

Comment: I'm currently using multi-threading to bypass the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure if this will help but, its worth noting due to the model you're using.

the M304X-V series had limitations due to the chipset used in its build. these limitations were related to frames, bitrate, text overlay, and amount of streams that could be pulled. it was an ambarella chip as opposed to what was used on P and Q series cameras. also, i remember there being some weird bugs in firmware version 6.15.X. if you used a different axis camera or updated the fw (if you are on a build of 6.15.X), id be curious to see the results.